# How to switch esc and caps lock using gsettings/gconftool-2 in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, gsettings, gnome2

There is an option for this in the preferences dialog, but I am looking for a way to do it in the commandline so that all these configurations can be automated.

I want to avoid xmodmap, because most of my system settings are done through gsettings, it's preferred to have this one also in a centralized place. Plus I don't like maintaining startup scripts, I would rather run a config script once and forget about the whole thing afterwards, and gsettings/gconftool-2 does that.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using Mint 17:

gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard options "['caps\tcaps:none']"